# How to tell Room to use provided Getters and Setters instead of using the PUBLIC attribute directly?

Tags: android, android-room

As described in the title, I need to have a *public* attribute "tag" and still have Room use the provided Getters and Setters, since these have some extra code.

This is because I'm making the @Entity-Class in question Parcelable by using [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler), which I don't want to use the Getters and Setters. Thus the attribute has to be *public*.

Code sampe:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "tag")
@Nullable
private String tag;

@Bindable
public String getTag() {
    return Objects.equals(tag, "") ? null : tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    if (this.tag == null || !this.tag.equals(tag)) {
        this.tag = tag;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.tag);
    }
}
```

Would be grateful for any ideas or insights. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It feels like you are trying to have one class serve several roles: as [a value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) for local persistence (Room), as [a DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) for passing data between processes (`Parcelable`), and as a piece of view data for data binding (`notifyPropertyChanged()`). IMHO, data binding is a dead-end technology, as Jetpack Compose is going to eliminate layout resources entirely. But, more generally, perhaps you should not have a single class trying to fill three disparate roles.

Comment: You're definitely right in that regard, integrating Data Binding got a bit more messy than I anticipated. I'll look into Jetpack Compose soon. I'll rethink how I manage the data in my app as well, thanks for the input.